# How to handle automatic character casing of names (first, last)?

Tags: c#, regex, user-interface, string-formatting, string-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone have a good Proper Case algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149/does-anyone-have-a-good-proper-case-algorithm)

I am currently in the unfortunate position of having a requirement thrust on me to display names of users that are loaded as part of a batch process from various sources (Excel, Access, etc...) with the correct character casing.

For example, if a name was loaded as "JOHN DOE" it should display as "John Doe".

Obviously this gets very complicated very quickly with names like McDonald, O'Reilly, LeBron, etc...

When researching this, the only thing I could find was advice saying to display the names in all caps, while this solution is preferred over showing names like Mcdonald, O'reilly and Lebron I would still like to be sure that I've done my due diligence before returning to them with "this is all you can have".

Are there any libraries out there (open source or paid) that could help accommodate this? I realize that it most likely cannot be perfect, but if it could cover 95~99% of the cases, then that should do fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: although that might not handle the McDonald/LeBron scenario...

Comment: Nothing can handle the McDonald/LeBron scenario without a dictionary of exceptional names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out Perl's [NameCase](http://search.cpan.org/~summer/Lingua-EN-NameCase/README) module, which does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. It obviously won't handle EVERY scenario, but I'm not sure of any feasible way that you could. At least most of the situations would be covered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TitleCase in the Globalization namespace:

```
    string myName = "JOHN QUINCY PUBLIC";
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    System.Globalization.TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
    string convertedName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(myName.ToLower());
    Console.WriteLine(convertedName);
```

will produce "John Quincy Public"

It will not handle apostrophes the way you want.

Comment: By looking at the comments in the MSDN article, this won't handle text that is loaded as all caps, unfortunately rendering it useless for my scenario...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but the code above changes "JOHN DOE" to "John Doe" (your example). The oddity of ToTitleCase ignoring all caps words is the reason for the call to ToLower().

Comment: Oh, my fault, I didn't see that "ToLower()" sandwiched in there.